# Error de promise Passport & NodeJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, promesas, passport

Estoy queriendo obtener los datos del usuario mediante el req en mi controlador para poder asociar el ID del usuario que se encuentra en la session al modelo de vacantes para saber cual es el autor de la vacante y mi consola me arroja el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la funcion que agregaria la vacante a la bd, estoy tomando los datos del usuario desde req.user, si hago un console.log a req.user me arroja Promesa pendiente

```
exports.addVacante = async (req, res) => {
    const vacante = new Vacante(req.body);
    
    vacante.author = req.user._id;
    
    const skillsVacante = req.body.skills.split(',');
    vacante.skills = skillsVacante;

    const nuevaVacante = await vacante.save();

    res.redirect(`/vacantes/${nuevaVacante.url}`);
}
```

Este es mi modelo de vacante

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const slug = require('slug');
const shortid = require('shortid');

const vacantesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: 'El nombre de la vacante es requerido',
        trim: true
    },
    company: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    location: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: 'La ubicacion es requerida'
    },
    salary: {
        type: String,
        default: 0,
        trim: true
    },
    contract: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true
    },
    skills: [String],
    candidates: [{
        name: String,
        email: String,
        cv: String
    }],
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Usuario',
        required: 'El autor es obligatorio'
    }
});

vacantesSchema.pre('save', function (next) {

    const url = slug(this.title);
    this.url = `${url}-${shortid.generate()}`

    next();
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Vacante', vacantesSchema);
```

Y mi modelo de usuario

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const usuariosSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    token: String,
    expira: Date
});

usuariosSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {

    if (!this.isModified('password')) {
        return next();
    }

    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    this.password = hash;
    next();
})

usuariosSchema.post('save', function (error, doc, next) {
    if (error.name === 'MongoServerError' && error.code === 1100) {
        next('Ese email ya existe');
    } else {
        next(error);
    }
})

usuariosSchema.methods = {
    compararPassword: function (password) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
    }
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('Usuario', usuariosSchema);
```

Para agregar el ID del author mi idea era hacer lo siguiente

```
vacante.author = req.user._id;
```

Este es mi archivo de configuracion de passport

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Usuario = mongoose.model('Usuario');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    }, async (email, password, done) => {
        const usuario = await Usuario.findOne({ email });

        if (!usuario) return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Usuario no existe'
        })

        const verificarPass = usuario.compararPassword(password);

        if (!verificarPass) return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Password incorrecto'
        })

        return done(null, usuario);
    }
));

passport.serializeUser((usuario, done) => done(null, usuario._id));
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    const usuario = Usuario.findById(id).exec();
    return done(null, usuario);
})

module.exports = passport;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error solucionado, el problema se encontraba en el archivo de configuracion de passport

```
passport.serializeUser((usuario, done) => done(null, usuario._id));
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    const usuario = **await** Usuario.findById(id).exec();
    return done(null, usuario);
})
```

Faltaba el await en la constante de usuario